# XSLT and XSL, who implements them?

Tags: java, xslt

I have come across `XSLT` and one of the key components of `XSLT` is `XSL`. As I understand, `XSLT` is used for transformation, for example, `XML` to an `HTML` document. For the transformation, it uses `XSL`.

Now, my question is:

Q1) Who implements `XSL`? Does it come as part of JDK?

Some code snippet which I have seen:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXML));
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("xslTransformationFile.xsl");
 ...
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslStream);
transformer.transform(source,result);
```

Most of them are coming from package: `javax.xml.transform.*` and it in `rt.jar` (part of jdk).

Q2) Does it mean the Java has support of `XSL` out of the box? That is, we don't need to download any additional jars for doing the transformation using `XSL`?

Q3) Are packages `javax.xml.transform.*` part of `JAXP`?

Can anyone help me in clarifying this?

Answer (score 2):

To try and answer your question:

(a) No, XSL is not a component of XSLT. Sometimes it is used as a synonym for XSLT, sometimes it is used to mean XSL-FO, occasionally in older Microsoft documents it is used to refer to a Microsoft language that pre-dated XSLT. But in none of these senses is XSL a component of XSLT.

(b) Who implements XSLT? It depends a bit whether you use the present tense or the past tense.

- There were many implementations of XSLT 1.0, some from big companies like IBM, Sun, Microsoft, and Oracle, some from start-ups and independent enthusiasts (for example libxslt from Daniel Veillard, or 4XSLT from Uche Ogbuji, or Sablotron from Petr Cimprich). Some of these implementations are still in use, but none are being actively developed.
- There were far fewer implementations of XSLT 2.0, the best known being my own Saxon product, Altova's RaptorXML server, IBM's Websphere processor, XmlPrime, and the MarkLogic processor.
- There are three companies who have stated that they are implementing XSLT 3.0: my own Saxonica, Exselt, and Altova.

The implementation that comes "out of the box" with the JDK is an XSLT 1.0 processor called Xalan, which is actually an amalgam of two original processors, LotusXSL from IBM (originally Lotus) and XSLTC from Sun.

Answer (score 1):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT, I don't think it mentions `XSL` anywhere as a component of `XSLT`. In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL you can see that, depending of the definition of the term `XSL`, `XSLT` together with `XSL-FO` and `XPath` forms part of specifications of the W3C `XSL` working group. As for implementations of XSLT in Java, Xalan and Saxon are widely used, Xalan is an XSLT 1.0 processor from Apache which was integrated in the Sun respectively Oracle JRE. Saxon exists with Saxon 6.5 as an XSLT 1.0 processor and with Saxon 9 as an XSLT 2.0 processor, continuously developed further to implement the progress made with the XSLT, XPath and XQuery specs so it by now implements the XPath 3.0 standard and the candidate recommendations of XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1. IBM Websphere is also known to have its own Java implementation of XSLT and XPath 2.0.

So if you want to use the Oracle JRE without any additional jars then you have access to XSLT 1.0 with the integrated version of Xalan, if you want XSLT 2.0 you need to use Saxon (available in an open source HE edition from Maven and http://saxon.sourceforge.net), for various features of the XSLT 3.0 language under development you need the commercial PE or EE editions from http://www.saxonica.com/.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not sure, but I did read somewhere that XSL is one of the major components of XSLT. I would check again and see if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: The acronym "XSL" is used by different people with different meanings, therefore it is best to avoid using it without further qualification.